# Code contracts. How suppress warnings on generated code?

Tags: code-contracts

How can I turn off static checks on my Linq2Sql code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can suppress checks on static code by marking the class(es) in question with `[ContractVerification(false)]`.

If your generated classes are `partial` you can create another file with another part(ial) in it and add it there, so it doesn't get overwritten when the code is regenerated.

Comment: For clarification, you can also suppress verification at the method level with this attribute.